# Rust can not change data because of borrowing rule

Tags: rust

I'm currently developing an evaluation program for a card game.

Therefore the user is uploading a list as `.txt` which got imported. The user can then execute different things to see different statistics.

I want to enable the user to change a specific card. Without getting to deep into the single functions, we have something like that as starting point:

```
 pub type Deck = Vec<(u32, Card)>;
 let card_categories = statistics::card_categories::make(&deck);
 match input_mode.to_lowercase().as_str(){
 ...
 "standard" => output::standard(&card_categories.standarad),
```

Here I borrow the data deck which is the described tuple.

I want to enable a user to search for a card in the deck and change it. For this reason I wrote a function:

```
pub fn change (new: &String, old: &mut Self ) {
    let dummy: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    match scryfallapi::request_card(&new) {
        Ok(t) => match scryfallapi::json_to_card(t, &dummy) {
            Ok(t) => {
                *old = t;
            }
            Err(e) => println!("{}", e),
        },
        Err(e) => println!("{}", e),
    };
}
```

The function is not perfect yet, but display's the desired function.

Now I need a function which may look like the following:

```
pub fn change_card(cardname: String, new_card: String, deck: &mut Deck) {
    for item in deck {
        Card::change(&new_card, &mut item.1);
    }
}
```

If I try to compile the following error is thrown:

```
cannot borrow 'deck' as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

The function should be placed like this:

```
 match input_mode.to_lowercase().as_str(){
 ...
 "standard" => output::standard(&card_categories.standarad),
 "change" => change_card(input::user_input(), input::user_input, &mut deck),
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that problem?

Edit:
Full error message:
[Full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkkV2.png)

Comment: Based on the limited information, I'd guess `card_categories` keeps a reference to the `deck`. But its hard to say, you haven't even included the full error message, which would indicate where the conflicting borrows are occurring.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You haven't included all of your code so it impossible for us to reproduce the error and try to fix it.

Comment: Hey all, thanks for your fast reply!

It is kinda hard to post the full code here since the project is already pretty advanced...

I gonna try to produce a minimal reproducible example

@kmdreko yes card_categories keeps the references to the dataset.

Comment: Please don't post _full_ code, but as pointed out by @apilat, try to extract the part that doesn't work into something that can be executed for example on the Rust playground. If I had to make a guess based on the code posted here, I'd say that you shouldn't use the for loop like you do, but use something like `for item in deck.iter_mut()`, as by default, the for loop syntactic sugar will use an immutable iter() call.

Comment: I solved the problem. 
The suggestion of @apilat, let me go through the logic carefully again. I tried to reproduce the error and figured that let card_categories was the problem. Since I refer here to a dataset I seek to change, Rust told me that this is not possible. Creating the dataset owned by card_categories every time I need it instead of at the beginning of the program, solved the problem.

Thank you all for your fast reply!